# Why initializing 1D array and 2D array to state in React js behaves differently

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

Example 1

```js
const arr   = ["a","b","c","d"]

class Alphabate extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {alpha:[...arr]}
        this.state.alpha[0] = "Changed"
        console.log(`inside consructor arr =  ${arr}`)
        
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            {this.state.alpha.map(
            x=><h3>{x}</h3>
            )}
             </div>
    }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Alphabate />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In this example 1 browser displays
Changed
b
c
d
and console logs "inside consructor arr =  a,b,c,d"

```js
const arr   = [["a","b"],
               ["c","d"]]

class Alphabate extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {alpha:[...arr]}
        this.state.alpha[0][0] = "Changed"
        console.log(`inside consructor arr =  ${arr}`)
        
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            {this.state.alpha.map(
            x=>x.map(
            y=><h3>{y}</h3>
            ))}
             </div>
    }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Alphabate />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

in this example browser displays 
Changed
b
c
d
and console logs "inside consructor arr =  Changed,b,c,d"

So my question is : why 1D array passed by value and 2D array pass by reference although i have passed copy of array [...arr] not the array

Comment: The spread syntax makes a **shallow** copy of the source array.

Comment: There are other questions here about deep copy operations. In general, deep copying can be very complicated, and you have to implement something yourself that works for your own application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have "2d" arrays. It has arrays of arrays. When you do this:

```
this.state = {alpha:[...arr]}
```

...you're only making a copy of the outer array; it still contains references to the same inner arrays that the original `arr` had. So when you change the contents of those inner arrays, you see that change regardless of which outer array you look through to get to the inner one.